# Will you bend or will you break?

Tags: riddle

You should be so grateful to me,

Yet I am not that well-known.

But so strong am I really,

I am comparable, even to bone.

But despite my power,

I can be as graceful as a flower.

So many forms I do take,

Look at all the things I can make!

Find me at your fingertips,

Maybe just above your head.

Even at the feet of giants,

Or with the smallest ones instead.

There's so much I do for you,

Can you answer this riddle true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> keratin

You should be so grateful to me,

Yet I am not that well-known.

But so strong am I really,

I am comparable, even to bone.

> a strong and versatile bio-building material

But despite my power,

I can be as graceful as a flower.

So many forms I do take,

Look at all the things I can make!

> used by organisms to create all kinds of structures

Find me at your fingertips,

Maybe just above your head.

Even at the feet of giants,

Or with the smallest ones instead.

> fingernails, hair, horns, toenails, claws, etc.

Comment: Seems I went a little too easy, well done.

Comment: I'd have struggled a little without the last section.  I was thinking maybe cartilage or something but the last part just gave it away.  +1